# Determinant is continuous using norm

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces, determinant

There is a theorem which says: If T is multilinear transformation T is continuous if and only if $\Vert T\Vert = sup_{\Vert x_i \Vert \leq 1} \Vert T(x)\Vert <\infty$

I wanted to show that $det:\mathbb{R}^n \times...\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ that for $(a_1,...,a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n \times...\times\mathbb{R}^n$, $a_i$ is the i-th row of a matrix, is continuous. So I have to show that its norm is finite.

$$\Vert det\Vert=sup_{\Vert a_1 \Vert \leq 1,...,{\Vert a_n \Vert \leq 1}}\Vert det(a_1,...,a_n)\Vert$$

But I don't know how to show that this norm is finite. Somehow I think it might be easy, but my brain doesn't work!

Comment: The norm of $det$ is $1$. You can prove this by orthogonalizing $a_i$.

Comment: @Zerox Why is that?

Comment: Apply Gram-Schmidt to $a_i$. A constant less than $1$ will occur when you normalizing them.

Comment: @Zerox I don't remember these methods. Would you please write it with more detail?

Comment: You can get a crude, but effective upper bound using geometric considerations. If you recall that $|\det(a_1, \ldots, a_n)|$ is the Lebesgue measure of the (hyper-)parallelepiped formed by the $n$ vectors, i.e. the convex hull of all possible sums of distinct vectors from $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$, then triangle inequality tells us that the set lies within the ball of radius $n$. The [measure of this ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball), $\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)} n^n$, is an upper bound on the determinant. Or, more crudely and simply, $(2n)^{2n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's easy.  $\det(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is a polynomial in the $a_{ij}$, so it's a continuous function, and therefore is bounded on a compact set.

Comment: I want to prove that det is continuous.

Comment: Do you not know that every polynomial is continuous?

Comment: Yes, but I want to show that it's continuous with definition of norm and multilinear